# Nginx proxy_pass with rewrite in url?

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting, reverse-proxy

I would like to implement a reverse proxy which redirect request of http://www.dummy.com/foo/bar/test to http://127.0.0.1/hello/world. I have tried to add rewrite before the pass and it seems not working ...

```
server {
listen 80;
listen [::]:80;

server_name www.dummy.com;

# access_log /var/log/nginx/upstream_log.log 

location / {
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html/dummy;
}

location /foo/bar/test {
    rewrite  ^/foo/bar/test /hello/world break;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1/;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/upstream_log.log upstream_logging;
}
```

}

Is there something missing or wrongly configured?

Comment: What isn't working? What is the result? Is there something in the log file?

Comment: It return http status 404 when I make a request to nginx  with postman. it seems the URL haven't being rewrite. I will post the log later. Thanks

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The above config works as expected... The other server was misconfigured when I test the above configuration.